# Error with datastax enterprise with hadoop enable and kerberos enable

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, kerberos, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have configured dse with hadoop enable and kerberos authentication. But I see this ERROR in the log. I can execute dse hadoop fs commands and nodetool commands but cannot run map reduce jobs.

**The following is the log :-**

```
ERROR [TASK-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-02-07 20:45:03,813 TaskTrackerRunner.java (line 128) Hadoop Task Tracker caused an exception in state STARTING:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/dse/hadoop/native/Linux-amd64- 64/bin/task-controller" (in directory "."): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.startProcess(Shell.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LinuxTaskController.setup(LinuxTaskController.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1470)
    at  com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerRunner.initService(TaskTrackerRunner.java:104)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerRunner.initService(TaskTrackerRunner.java:31)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.ServiceRunner.run(ServiceRunner.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 10 more
ERROR [Thrift:8] 2014-02-07 20:45:12,624 TNegotiatingServerTransport.java (line 293) An  error occurred during transport negotiation
com.datastax.bdp.transport.common.TTransportNegotiationException: Improper authentication type requested.  Requested auth: No authentication with service principal: FRAMED_TRANSPORT_FAKE_PRINCIPAL, Allowed auth: Kerberos
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getUnderlyingFactory(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:485)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.handleTransportNegotiation(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:286)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:192)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:517)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
ERROR [Thrift:8] 2014-02-07 20:45:12,625 TNegotiatingServerTransport.java (line 524) Failed to open server transport.
com.datastax.bdp.transport.common.TTransportNegotiationException: An error occurred during transport negotiation
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.handleTransportNegotiation(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:294)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:192)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:517)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.datastax.bdp.transport.common.TTransportNegotiationException: Improper authentication type requested.  Requested auth: No authentication with service principal: FRAMED_TRANSPORT_FAKE_PRINCIPAL, Allowed auth: Kerberos
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getUnderlyingFactory(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:485)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.handleTransportNegotiation(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:286)
    ... 7 more
ERROR [Thrift:8] 2014-02-07 20:45:12,626 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 219) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open server transport: unknown
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:525)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:408)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.datastax.bdp.transport.common.TTransportNegotiationException: An error occurred during transport negotiation
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.handleTransportNegotiation(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:294)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.open(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:192)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:517)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.datastax.bdp.transport.common.TTransportNegotiationException: Improper authentication type requested.  Requested auth: No authentication with service principal: FRAMED_TRANSPORT_FAKE_PRINCIPAL, Allowed auth: Kerberos
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport$Factory.getUnderlyingFactory(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:485)
    at com.datastax.bdp.transport.server.TNegotiatingServerTransport.handleTransportNegotiation(TNegotiatingServerTransport.java:286)
    ... 7 more
WARN [TASK-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-02-07 20:45:13,828 MetricsSystemImpl.java (line 200) Source name ugi already exists!
```

**This is the task controller :-**

-rwsr-x--- 1 root cassandra 40111 Jan  9 18:14 /usr/share/dse/hadoop/native/Linux-amd64-64/bin/task-controller

**I am using** 
DSE 3.2.3
Java 1.7.0_25

I have configured properly in cassandra.yaml, dse.yaml, core-site.xml, mapre-site.xml, /etc/default/dse files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not start the daemon from root home directory. This sounds weird but try to start the daemon other than root home Directory.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/dse/hadoop/native/Linux-amd64- 64/bin/task-controller" (in directory "."): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)

Above clearly shows the user doesn't have the permission to run it. Change the permission so that it has execute permission for the user. Use chmod to change the permission

Comment: Well You cannot change the permissions of that file to anything else other than 4750 and the owner should be root. I tried that too before, it gave me the following error "task-controller must be chmod 4750 instead of 777"